# Using RequestFactory and GAE Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

I m developing an application on Google App Engine (1.7) using Google Web Toolkit (2.4) and Eclipse as IDE. To deploy my application I need to create entities and using GAE datastore to store my entities values. Before this summer I noticed that there was an "RPC service" which could create all the appropriate entity proxies, value proxies and locators classes needed to use the requestfactory framework to store entities but as I recently noticed after an update these featured removed from the eclipse plug in.

Does anybody know any way to use requestfactory without the need to manually create a list of classes (proxies, valueproxies, locators) for every entity in my application?

Thnx!!

Comment: I recently noticed that "objectify" is a solution for requestfactory users. Any experience from that?

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way. It would be cool to have a eclipse plugin where you can click on the Server-Class an say "create proxy, locatotor, etc.".

What you can do, to be faster is:
Just choose **Extract Interface...** from the Refactor menu on the server class and safe this one as proxy interface.

If you use objectify, than you don't need a server side class, thats true.